# Word Matching Exercise Game

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple program that matches words with descriptions. The program should do the following.

1. Allow a user to enter a set of inputs: keys and descriptions.
2. When the user clicks generate html a textarea should be created with html to be rendered in the word matching exercise.
3. When the user clicks show answer the program should show the keys with the corresponding descriptions.
4. When the user clicks add more new inputboxes are generated. After this state change when the user clicks generate html the new input boxes should be used to update the html shown in the text box.
5. When the user clicks render html the html from the textarea should be rendered below the textarea.
6. When the user clicks reset the textarea, controls, and rendered html should be removed. The program should return to the original state.
7. When the html from the text is rendered the descriptions should be randomized.

This is the html

```
<div id="maincontentstyle">
        <div id="boxstyle">
          <h3 id= "title">Section 5.2 Word Matching Exercise</h3>
          <div class="row">
            <div id="inputs" class="column column-1">
                <div id="inputBoxes" class="inputBoxes">
                    <title>Input:</title>
                    <div class="row">
                      Title: <input id= "title_input" type="text">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                      Key Term 1: <input id="el1" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      Description 1: <input id="dl1" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      Key Term 2: <input id="el2" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      Description 2: <input id="dl2" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="padding: 3px">
                  <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="add_more()">add more</button>
                </span>
                <span style="padding: 3px">
                  <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="generate_html()">generate html</button>
                </span>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="results" class="row">
          </div>
          <div id="renderedHTML" class="row">
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
 <script>
    // initially html is not generated.
    var htmlGenerated = false;
    // number of inputs start out as 2.
    var numberOfInputs = 2;
    // initially no addtional inputs have been added.
    var addMore = false;
    // initially html is not rendered
    var htmlRendered = false;
    // initialize the answer.
    var answer = '';

    function shuffle(a){
      for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
        j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
        if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
      }
      return a
    }
      
    function reset() {
      // reset the htmGenerated to false.
      htmlGenerated = false;
      htmlRendered  = false;
      numberOfInputs = 2;
      var someVarName = true;
      sessionStorage.setItem("someVarKey1", someVarName);
      window.location.reload();
    }

    function show_answer() {
      // retrieve the keys and descriptions. Then load them into their respective arrays.
      const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
      const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
      let elArray = [];
      let dlArray = [];
      const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
      e_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) elArray.push(i.value) });
      d_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) dlArray.push(i.value) });

      //reset the answer once the generate_html() is called.
      answer = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++) {
          answer += `${elArray[i]}`;
          answer += ':';
          answer += `${dlArray[i]}`;
          answer += '\n';
      }
      jAlert(answer, 'Correct Match');
    }

    function generate_html() {
      // retrieve the keys and descriptions. Then load them into their respective arrays.
      const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
      const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
      let elArray = [];
      let dlArray = [];
      const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
      e_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) elArray.push(i.value) });
      d_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) dlArray.push(i.value) });

      console.log("generating answer");
      console.log(answer);

      //If we added more
      if(addMore){
        // then delete the old textarea.
        if(document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea")){
          textarea = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
          textarea.remove();
        }
        if(document.getElementById("program1")){
          // delete the controls.
          controls = document.getElementById("program1");
          controls.remove();
        }
      }

    
      //if the html isn't generated or if we added more then create it.
      if(!htmlGenerated || addMore){
        //fetch the results box
        results = document.getElementById("results");
        
        //create textarea
        textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("id","generated_html_textarea");
        
        // initialize blank html
        let html = '';
        html += '<div id=\"maincontentstyle\">\n'
        html += '\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t<div id=\"boxstyle\">\n'
        html += '\t\t\t<h3 id=\"h3style\">'+title+"</h3>\n";

        //create key inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<div class="source">\n' 
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id="s';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">\n';
          html += `\t\t\t\t\t\t\t${elArray[i-numberOfInputs]}\n`;
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</center>\n'
  
        //create description inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<table id=\"tablestyle\">\n'
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n'
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id="row';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='">\n';
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\"t';
          html += id;
          html +='" class=\"ltarget\">'
          html +='</div>\n' 
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n'
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\"d'
          html += id
          html += '\">\n'
          html +=`\t\t\t\t\t\t\t${dlArray[i-numberOfInputs]}\n`;
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n' 
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t</center>\n'
        html += '\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t</center>\n'
        html += '</div>'

        // html generation is done.
        htmlGenerated = true;
        textarea.value = html;
        results.appendChild(textarea);
        
        if(addMore)
          addMore = false;

        // Generate reset, show answer, , and render html buttons
        controls = document.createElement("div");
        controls.setAttribute("id","program1");
        controls.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        controls.innerHTML +=  '<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button><button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id = "audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"/> </a> </span> </span>';
        results.appendChild(controls);
      }
    }

    function add_more() {
      // we've added more inputs.
      addMore = true;
      
      // increment the number of inputs.
      numberOfInputs++;

      //fetch the input boxes.
      inputs = document.getElementById("inputBoxes");
      
      //create a new row for a key term.
      row = document.createElement("div");
      row.setAttribute("class","row");

      // set the key term text.
      row.innerHTML = "Key Term ";
      row.innerHTML +=numberOfInputs;
      row.innerHTML +=" :";

      // create the input for the key.
      key = document.createElement("input");
      key.setAttribute("id","el"+numberOfInputs);

      //add the key to the row.
      row.appendChild(key);

      //create a row for the new description.
      row2 = document.createElement("div");
      row2.setAttribute("class","row");

      // set the description text.
      row2.innerHTML = "Description  "
      row2.innerHTML+=numberOfInputs;
      row2.innerHTML+=" :";

      // create the description input
      description = document.createElement("input");
      description.setAttribute("id","dl"+numberOfInputs);

      // add the description to the row.
      row2.appendChild(description);

      // add the rows for the key and the description to the inputBoxes.
      inputs.appendChild(row);
      inputs.appendChild(row2);
    }

    function render_html(){
      // was html rendered?
      if(!htmlRendered){
        textarea  = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
        generated_html = textarea.value;
        console.log(generated_html);
        maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
        rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("id","rendered_html");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        rendered_html.innerHTML +=  generated_html;
        maincontentstyle.appendChild(rendered_html);
        htmlRendered = true;
      }
    }
</script>
```

I've created four functions reset(), show_answer(), generate_html(), and add_more(). This works, but it could be optimized.